# Toggle if element has class

Tags: jquery

Trying to toggle if an arrow is facing down or right. It is set by default to be facing right and when a div is clicked it is meant to change to down. It does this correctly then it doesn't change back to facing right when the div is clicked again

```js
if ('#1_arrow'.class != 'rotate') {
   $('#1_arrow').addClass('rotate');
}else if('#1_arrow'.class == 'rotate'){
   $('#1_arrow').removeClass('rotate');
}
```

```html
<div id="images" class="super_container">
    <div class="header" id="1_open"><img src="./resources/images/icons/arrow.png" class="arrow" id="1_arrow">Images</div>
    <div id="images_container" class="containers">
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`'#1_arrow'` is a string. It doesn't have property called `class`. Use jquery `hasClass`:

```
if ($('#1_arrow').hasClass( 'rotate' )) {
   $('#1_arrow').addClass('rotate');
} else {
   $('#1_arrow').removeClass('rotate');
}
```

Or a simplified version of this code:

```
$('#1_arrow').toggleClass('rotate');
```

Comment: Nope this is unnecessary, since the class name to be checked and the class name needs to be assigned are same. you can suggest OP, `.toggleClass('classname')`

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `.toggleClass('rotate')`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$("#1_arrow").hasClass("rotate") )  {   // if it doesn't have a class, add it
     $('#1_arrow').addClass('rotate');
} else {
     $('#1_arrow').removeClass('rotate');
}
```

Just add a class when it doesn't have.